# How to say 反常识的 in English?

Tags: translation, grammar, word-choice, usage, expressions

How to properly translate `反常识的` to English in academic writing? I want to express a surprising and unusual phenomenon that shouldn't appear in an experiment, which is not expected and against the physical principle.

For example,

> However, it is quite `反常识的` that the performance of A is .... blah...

Comment: How about *counterintuitive* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean "Counterintuitive".

Answer (score 0):

Google result for 反常识的 is "unconventional". It doesn't seem  to fit the description in the context you described.

I think the word you are looking for is [ "**inconceivable**" *(adj): beyond reason, belief* ] - implies a finding seemingly defies the law of physic or conventional believes

"inconceivable" in Chinese is 不可思議; 無法想像

Side note:

*If an experiment's result seemingly defies the law of physic, the most likely cause would be: 1. Mistakes were made during the experiment. 2. Someone forged the result 3. The previous notion was wrong.*

**Edit** (add from my comment):

反" contains the meaning of 'to counter' . Therefore, someone think "Counter-intuitive" contains the word 'counter' must be the right answer and my answer suggested giving up the phrase "反常识的" and use "不可思議" or "無法想像" to describe "a surprising and unusual phenomenon" . Actually "counter-intuitive" is not much different from "unconventional"- meaning something that is not conventionally done or intuitively thought

For example: A green button instead of a red button activate self-destruct command is 'counter-intuitive' because we usually label dangerous function with the color red. I would translate 'counter-intuitive' as "違反直覺的" and "**反常识的**" as "**against common sense**"

Comment: I don't understand why this answet is downvoted.

Comment: @Nathan Explosion  "反" contains the meaning of 'to counter' .  Therefore, someone think  "Counter-intuitive" contains the word  'counter' must be the right answer and my answer suggested giving up  the phrase "反常识的" and use "不可思議" or  "無法想像" to describe "a surprising and unusual phenomenon" . Actually "counter-intuitive" is the same as "unconventional"- meaning something that is not conventionally done or intuitively thought

Comment: Now I added "against common sense"  as the translation of "反常识的" , Since  反 also contain the meaning of "against". I hope that satisfies someone's need for literal translation

Answer (score 0):

常识=common sense

反常识==incredible